# If Button clicked - do animation to image Swift Playgrounds

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-playground, swift4.2

My goal is simple. When a button is clicked, the button should fade out and so should another image on the screen. I am using **Swift Playgrounds**. **I have already got the button to fade out when clicked working**. The main problem is getting the image on the screen to fade out once the button is clicked.

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import AVFoundation
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let title = UIImage(named: "Picture1")
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: title) //this is the image I want to fade out when the button is clicked
        imageView.image = title
        imageView.frame.size.width = 570
        imageView.frame.size.height = 140
        imageView.frame.origin.x = 100
        imageView.frame.origin.y = 0
        imageView.alpha = 0

        let button = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.custom) as UIButton
        let image = UIImage(named: "startbutton4.png") as UIImage?
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 265, y: 300, width: 249, height: 85)
        button.setImage(image, for: [])
        button.contentMode = .center
        button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit


        button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(button)
        view.addSubview(imageView)
    }

    @objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton) {
        sender.isHighlighted = false
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
           sender.alpha = 0
        }, completion: nil) // <--- this right here is the button fading out 
    }

}
let master = MyViewController()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = master
```

If anyone has any idea how to do this, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i understand is you want to hide button ... once button is hidden you want to show image .. here is the code for that.. i hope it will help

```
func buttonAction(sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isHighlighted = false
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
       sender.alpha = 0
    }, completion: { success in
        if success {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
           imageView.alpha = 1
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: this would work, but the problem is that the function doesn't know what imageView is. Since imageView was declared in the viewDidLoad function.

Comment: is there any way for the obj c function to know what imageView is?

Comment: You need to send image view as parameter  or declare out side didload()

Comment: how would i send a second parameter in the button.addTarget

Comment: you can't send second param .. you need to subclass UIButton for that which is not a good approach .. so use instance variable instead